# Why :new edited buffer prevents :bn without naming and saving?

Tags: nvim

I use that buffer as scratchpad but nvim makes that really really hard. Why current settings are default?

Comment: (1) I was going to say “Please use complete sentences”, but then I saw that, technically, you did.  My point is that your question is so short that it feels like a text message or a tweet.  I suggest that you make it detailed enough that a user who is a novice in `vi` will be able to understand it.  (2) My opinion is that the title of a Stack Exchange question should be like the title of a book or movie — enough to tell you what the thing is *about* without telling you the whole story. (This is not official policy, and some people disagree.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) My opinion is that the *body* of a Stack Exchange question should be like the text of a book or the screenplay of a movie — it should make sense even if you don’t look at the title. In other words, don’t treat the title as the first line of the question. What is “that buffer”? *How* does nvim make using the buffer as a scratchpad hard? What “current settings” are you asking about? Your question doesn’t say. (Going back to point 1, it is not clear *even if* you take the title into account.) (This is not official policy either, and there is some disagreement about it.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Why shouldn't that be the default? I'd think most applications of `:new` would actually be for creating a new file. What you want is a scratch buffer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11311/205